# How to fix 'Error438: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method' in this code?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I get

> Error 438 : Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method 
>   when I try to paste from one workbook to another. Is the syntax wrong?

```
Sub ImportScen()

Dim ALMscen As Workbook
Set ALMscen = ActiveWorkbook

Dim Wrkbk as Workbook
Set Wrkbk = Workbooks.Add
Wrkbk.SaveAs Filename:=filepath & "\" & file_name & ".xlsx"

ALMscen.Range(Cells(firstrow, 6), Cells(lastrow, 15)).Copy _
    Destination:=Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
'Error occurs on these two previous lines 

Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(numscen * 115 + 1, 15)).Value = 0

ALMscen.Range(.Cells(firstrow, 16), Cells(lastrow, 23)).Copy _
    Destination:=Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P2")
'Error occurs on these two previous lines 

ALMscen.Range(Cells(firstrow, 25), Cells(lastrow, 34)).Copy _
    Destination:=Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X2")
'Error occurs on these two previous lines 

Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 34), Cells(numscen * 115 + 1, 34)).Value = 0
Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 35), Cells(numscen * 115 + 1, 35)).Value = 20
Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 36), Cells(numscen * 115 + 1, 36)).Value = 95
```

Comment: A Range object is the property of a Worksheet object, not a Workbook object.  So you need to qualify your range reference with a worksheet -- for example `ALMscen.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range...`.  Also, I see that you haven't defined firstrow and lastrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALMscen.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(firstrow, 6), Cells(lastrow, 15)).Copy _
Destination:=Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
```

Where: Sheet(1) is the origin sheet of your workbook,also you can call the sheet like this `Sheet("_sheetname_")`. Where *sheetname* is the actual name of your worksheet.

**Mor info**
Here you are doing it right `Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 34), Cells(numscen * 115 + 1, 34)).Value = 0` because you call a object inside a collection.

Look: 
A workbook contain sheets and if you want to call any sheet you need to respect the order
i saw you

`Wrkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 34), Cells(numscen * 115 + 1, 34)).Value = 0`